# How to call two functions on click

Tags: php, javascript

How can I get an id in PHP when an anchor is clicked, and at the same time call a Javascript function?

The Javascript function works when `href="#"` and and PHP is called when using `href="index.php?id=1"`.

How can I both at same time on when an anchor is clicked? I'm also calling function onclick="js()"

```
echo "<li>" ."<a href='#t.php?id=1' onmousedown='div(2)'>".$pro[$i]."</a>" ."</li>";

     }  
if (isset($_GET['id']))
     {
        echo "HELLO";
     }
```

Comment: Please provide some code you've written to give us a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can get it using `this.`

Comment: echo "<li>" ."<a href='#t.php?id=1' onmousedown='div(2)'>".$pro[$i]."</a>" ."</li>";

           
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
         {
            echo "HELLO";
         }

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do it.  Which way you use really, really, really, really depends upon what you want the Javascript to do, and what you want the PHP to do.

Answer (score 0):

When a click occurs, the Javascript handler will be fired, then the browser will load the page specified in the `href` attribute.

If you wish to execute some Javascript before the redirection happens, continue using your `onclick` event:

```
<a href="index.php?id=1" onclick="doSomethingInJavascript()">...
```

Your Javascript function can return `false` if you wish to cancel the redirection to the PHP page, if necessary.

Also be aware that AJAX calls will allow you to call a PHP script and perform other Javascript functionality, all without loading a new page.